# Contact Form 7 - mail_failed

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Wordpress 4.9.20 running Abiko theme website.

I have a contact form 7, and when I submit it, it throws the following error:

```
{into: "#wpcf7-f15498-p7-o1"
message: "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."
status: "mail_failed"}
```

Yesterday I had captcha 2 and it was throwing a `spam` error, now I updated to captcha 3 and it throws mail_failed. The website it not used frequently and I don't know when the error started.

Are there any backend logs I can check? Or I need to install a plugin for everything on WP? What should I do to debug this? I haven't worked with WP before.

Answer (score 2):

A few things can cause this error. What color border is around the error "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later." Orange or red?

Red tells you that the form is not sending and is caused by your server not sending the email. Try contacting the host.

Orange tells you that your form is not sending because of a spam issue. First try removing the [recaptcha] shortcode and test again to see if the problem remains.

If it still has the issue then you have some sort of odd configuration going. Generally there are two different ways of fixing this issue: You can either create a business email address with your domain name and use the new email in your contact form settings, or you can install and set up an SMTP plugin and use a dedicated email sending service.